# Paste text between specific lines in a text file? (R)

Tags: r, paste, cat

Let's say I have this .txt file:

```
here is line 1
here is line 2
here is line 3
here is line 4
```

and I want to paste this string between lines 3 and 4:

```
here is line 3.5
```

How can I accomplish this? At first I thought by perhaps writing what I have below might work, but it just erases the other lines.

```
cat("",
"",
"",
"this is line 3.5",sep="\n", file = "file.txt")
```

Comment: Are you trying to modify the file so that line is placed between lines 3 and 4? Are you just trying to print the lines to the R console?

Answer (score 3):

Here's one approach: define a function to insert a string at a specific position, then apply the function to your data, then write the file back to disk.

```
# if the text is from a file `fname` you'd use `dat <- readLines(fname)` 
dat <- c("here is line 1",
         "here is line 2",
         "here is line 3",
         "here is line 4")

text_to_insert <- "here is line 3.5"

insert_line_at <- function(dat, to_insert, insert_after){
  pre <- dat[1:insert_after]
  post <- dat[(insert_after+1):length(dat)]
  return(c(pre, to_insert, post))
}

dat_inserted <- insert_line_at(dat, text_to_insert, insert_after=3)
```

Then write the new text back to whatever file you want it in:

```
writeLines(dat_inserted, "output_filename.txt")
```

If you are working with really big files it might be better to use a command line utility like [`sed`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x23170.html) or [`awk`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/awk.html). But if you wanna stick to R then the above is a clean + straightforward approach.

Note that you can insert a character vector `to_insert` of arbitrary length (including zero) -- not just a single string as in your example. So the function might be more aptly named `insert_lines_at()`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way you can do it. This will overwrite "file.txt" to have the extra line. Perhaps not the most efficient or generalizable.

```
x = readLines("file.txt")
x = c(x[1:3], "this is line 3.5", x[4])
writeLines(x, "file.txt")
```

To print to the console, do

```
cat(x, sep = '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to @lefft's answer, this function accounts for the edge case of inserting at the beginning or end of a file (also handles the edge case of inserting past the end of a file)

```
# if the text is from a file `fname` you'd use `dat <- readLines(fname)` 
dat <- c("here is line 1",
         "here is line 2",
         "here is line 3",
         "here is line 4")

text_to_insert <- "here is line 3.5"

insert_line_after <- function(dat, to_insert, insert_after){

  # edge cases: inserting at the end or the beginning (or past the end)
  if(insert_after >= length(dat)) {
    return(c(dat, to_insert))
  } else if(insert_after == 0) {
    return(c(to_insert, dat))
  }

  pre <- dat[1:insert_after]
  post <- dat[(insert_after+1):length(dat)]
  return(c(pre, to_insert, post))
}
```